# Como ordenar una lista enlazada linkedlist en java

Tags: java

Buen día ,como puedo ordenar una lista enlazada en java de menor a mayor en base al dato que contiene cada Nodo ,sin actualizar los datos, sino que acomodar las referencias en memoria en base al dato contenido en cada nodo , espero haberme explicado.
dejo un diagramita que hice con el que me estaba ayudando ,intente implementarlo pero no funciono.[image: diagrama]

```
public void ordenarDeMenoraMayor (){
    Nodo jj,x,y,z,aux = null;
    jj = head;
    while (jj.next!=null){
        x = jj;
        y = jj.next;
        z = jj.next.next;
        if(x.datum > y.datum){
               aux = x;
               jj = y;
               jj.next = aux;
               aux.next = z;
        }
        if(aux == head){
                head = y;
                }
jj = jj.next;
    }
}
```

Esta es mi clase Nodo

```
public class Nodo {
public int datum;
public Nodo next;
}
```

Esta es una de las formas en la que agrego los nodos por si quieren testear

```
public void preppend(int dato){
    Nodo tmp;
    tmp = new Nodo();
    tmp.datum = dato;
    tmp.next = head;
    head = tmp;
    
}
```

y así imprimo la lista de nodos

```
public void imprimir(){
Nodo tmp;
tmp = head;
while (tmp!=null){
    System.out.println(tmp.datum);
    tmp = tmp.next;
}

}
```

Comment: para empezar, creo que puedo detectar varios problemas. jj.next.next sera null si es el nodo actual es el ultimo. ¿Y te debería arrojar un NullPointerException? Ademas, si funciona como los iteradores, al momento de hacer next, estas avanzando una posición, por tanto en cada bucle avanzas varias veces. Voy copiarme el codigo y trastear con el

Comment: @RuDaHee Tiene pinta de estar usando una clase propia `Nodo`, donde seguramente tenga declarado `Nodo next;`, es decir, next siempre va a ser un objeto de nodo (o null), no es un método con lo cual no *avanza* el puntero... Por otro lado, @JuanUbce, cuando cambias una referencia al `next`, también deberías cambiar el `next` del anterior! Por cierto... nombrar las variables de manera correcta ayuda ***MUCHÍSIMO*** a la hora de que otros lean tu código... porque vaya rollo con `x`, `z`, `y`, `jj` y `aux`...

Comment: @RuDaHee vale bro gracias ,si necesitas alguna otra parte del código avisas

Comment: @Benito-B mm y como debería llamarles bro? lo hice asi para no tener tantas variables de nombre auxiliar y si ,tengo una clase nodo propia , veré si puedo actualizar la pregunta para agregarla, aunque solo tiene dos variables ,dato y siguiente que pues es el next.